# How to send ajax request from knockout js to controller php file

Tags: magento2

I am overriding shipping address in mixin js file , I want id in my controller when we move from checkout page next step.

```
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
 /*global alert*/
 define([
     'jquery',
     'mage/utils/wrapper',
     'mage/storage',
      'uiComponent',
     'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
 ], function ($, wrapper, storage,Component, quote) {
     'use strict';

     return function (setShippingInformationAction) {

         return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
             var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();
             console.log("Before");
            console.log(shippingAddress);
                     var countryId = quote.shippingAddress().countryId;
                
                 if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }
            
            var attribute1 = shippingAddress.customAttributes.find(
                function (element) {
                    return element.attribute_code === 'eventid';
                }
            );
            var attribute = shippingAddress.customAttributes.find(
                function (element) {
                    return element.attribute_code === 'custom_field';
                }
            );
            shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['custom_field'] = attribute.value;

            shippingAddress['extension_attributes']['eventid'] = attribute1.value;
              
            
             
             // ajax call
             
    
            var param = 'ajax=1';
                $.ajax({
                    showLoader: true,
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/magento237new/test2.php',
                    data: {eventid: attribute1.value},
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        
                                             
             console.log("After");
            console.log(shippingAddress);
             return originalAction(); // 
         });
     };
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an ajax request to any PHP controller using knockout js so please update the below code:

`var param = 'ajax=1'; $.ajax({ showLoader: true, url: 'http://127.0.0.1/magento237new/test2.php', data: {eventid: attribute1.value}, type: "POST", dataType: 'json' }).done(function (data) { console.log(data); });`

To

`var url = '/route/contorller/action'; var param = {eventid: attribute1.value}; $.ajax({ async: false, // required showLoader: true, url: url, data: param, type: "POST", dataType: 'json', success : function (response) { console.log(response); } });`